# disable date in jquery datepicker after some time

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've created a datepicker for one of my client.
They are in a flower delivery business and they offer same day delivery for order which is placed before 12 noon. so I created a following code for that.  The basic overview of its functionality is:

-> Disable current date if the time is greater than 12:00 (noon) so that customer can not put order for same day delivery.

But somehow recently one order can at 6PM for same day delivery. Which is an issue.

This is what I did so far:

```
<?php
// This is how i check for current date and time and if the delivery cut off time is passed add that date to disabled dates array. so customer can not put order of the current date.
 current_day = date( "w" );
 $todays_cut_off_time = get_option("weekday_cut_off_time_$current_day");
  $todays_cut_off_time = strtotime($todays_cut_off_time);
  $current_time = date( 'H:i', current_time( 'timestamp', 0 ) );
  $current_time = strtotime($current_time);
  if($todays_cut_off_time < $current_time)
  {
    $disabled_dates_array[] = date("m/d/Y");
  } 
?>
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

 var disableddates = <?php echo $disabled_delivery_dates; ?>;  //contains list of disabled dates by admin.

 exceptions    = <?php echo $holiday_exception_dates; ?>; //contains dates those are exceptional

  function DisableSpecificDates(date) {

   var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
   if(m <= 9)
     m = '0'+m;
     var d = date.getDate();
   if(d <= 9)
    d = '0'+d;
    var y = date.getFullYear();


  // First convert the date in to the mm-dd-yyyy format
  // Take note that we will increment the month count by 1
  var currentdate = m + '/' + d + '/' + y ;

  // We will now check if the date belongs to exceptions array
  for (var i = 0; i < exceptions.length; i++) {

 // Now check if the current date is in disabled dates array.
 if (jQuery.inArray(currentdate, exceptions) != -1 ) {

 return [true];

 }

 }

 // We will now check if the date belongs to disableddates array
 for (var i = 0; i < disableddates.length; i++) {

 // Now check if the current date is in disabled dates array.
 if (jQuery.inArray(currentdate, disableddates) != -1 ) {

 return [false];

  }

 }

 // In case the date is not present in disabled array, we will now check if it is a weekend.
// We will use the noWeekends function
//var weekenddate = jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
  var day = date.getDay();
  return [(<?php echo $disabled_week_day; ?>), ''];

}
function FindMinDate(date){
  return 0;
 }
jQuery( "#delivery_date" ).datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
   minDate: 0,
   beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates
});
});
 </script>
```

Can somebody please guide me in the right direction to get this done. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want the user not to choose the current date after 12 noon ?? but it is still the same date , It is like you want to behave the calendar unusual ?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Sorry I dont understand that "unusual", but yes, I dont want the user to choose current date after 12 noon. so with the help of php code i added current date to disable dates if the time is greater than 12.  but somehow it doesn't work for few time.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu do you think it has something to do with timezone? Like i said one of customer was able to select to select the current date even after 12noon. But when I check on my computer it doesn't allow me to select the current date after 12noon.

Comment: obviously, if your user are restricted to choose back date, then it is already backdate , better to use date of your server to get the job done, if you want to disable it everywhere, in that case , you are doing a really foolish thing as the user in some region will be unable to choose the current date with out any reason.

Comment: yes, you are right, I thought I'm doing something foolish! haha! and that's why i need help. What do you mean by "If you want to disable it everywhere"? i want to disable it for eveyrbody from anywhere if time is greater than 12noon.

Comment: you want to restrict people as per your time, that is the problem ?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu ok so any suggestion about how i can get this done! I need to get this working in the way I mentioned.

Comment: I need more idea about what ever happening , for now, I think it should be working well , just you are confused .

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu ok ill try to explain in more detail. When I developed and checked, the code was working fine as I mentioned. It didn't allow me to put order for current date if the time passed cut time for the day. But recently I've received an order at 18:47 and the datepicker allow him to select the current date for delivery even if the time has passed the cut of time for the day. Does that make sense?

Comment: the current date for me and you it is 11/02/2016 is it the same date for everyone ? NO. so if the user is on date 10/02/2016 he should be able to choose the date and there is no problem in it.

Comment: I understand your point. But how come a guy on 06/02/2016 at 18:47 was able to select 06/02/2016 for delivery after the cut of time for that day. Any guesses on that?
At that time, my wordpress time was set to UTC-6. And the guy put order from same time zone UTC-6. Any guesses? I really appreciate your help.